# Error while deploying app(Nodejs + sqlite3) on Heroku

Tags: node.js, sqlite, heroku, deployment, error-handling

I am trying to deploy my app (Node.js) on Heroku which uses a sqlite3 database, deployment is done but while running the app I am getting the following error:

- 2020-04-23T10:07:50.747074+00:00 app[web.1]: App started on port 5000
- 2020-04-23T10:07:50.748081+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to the SQLite database.
- 2020-04-23T10:07:50.748081+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to the SQLite database.
- 2020-04-23T10:08:48.280947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
- 2020-04-23T10:08:52.004314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=backendthemesdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=470f5cfb-58e4-4ab0-b666-14880d5c31a8 fwd="43.241.194.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
- 2020-04-23T10:08:53.642688+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=backendthemesdemo.herokuapp.com request_id=f2d12092-9809-463b-89c1-eb5fcd8b267f fwd="43.241.194.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
- 2020-04-23T10:30:38.831607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

Comment: 1. You hardcoded binding the app to port 5000 instead of binding it to `$PORT`. Thus when accessing the web page it will not work. 2. sqlite3 is not a suitable database for Heroku due to the file system being reseted once a day.

Comment: Thanks, @Tin Nguyen but is there any way we can use sqlite3 database through third party application or server ?

Comment: sqlite is serverless. You will need to use postgresql, mongodb etc